# variate transformation

Tags: data-transformation, references

logarithmic transformation which is used to stabilize the variance of the distribution of the sample variances , $S^2$.

$$S^2\sim^{asy}  N(\sigma^2,\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1})$$

Is that $$log S^2\sim N(log\sigma^2,\frac{2}{n})$$ or,

$$log S^2\sim N(log\sigma^2,\frac{2}{n-1})$$

I need online reference of logarithmic transformation.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but you don't take the log of the variance, you take the log of the values. You can then take the variance of the transformed variable, and you can use whichever denominator is appropriate (sample or population); e.g.

```
set.seed(102105)
x <- exp(rnorm(1000))
var(x)
var(log(x))
```

or are you asking how $var(log(x))$ relates to $var(x)$?

Comment: It would be helpful if you noted what language / program this code is using? Actually, methinks all postings that use code should necessarily do this.

Comment: Good point.... `R` seems to be the default around here, and that's what this is in.

Comment: Good to know - thought it was goobledegook. So is this code above performing a symbolic algebraic transformation of the user's problem? Or it is a numeric data procedure? No output is given?